# Can't read string from .plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have created .plist where I put string which is used for google analytics and the problem is that the string can't be pass to that code in appdelegate.m where is google analytics code.

configuration.plist looks like this :
GAnalytics , string , "XXXXXXXX"

I have create the .h and .m file for it to read it

**configuration.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Configuration : NSObject

+(instancetype)sharedConfig;

-(NSString *)GoogleAnalyticsID;

@end
```

**configuration.m**

```
#import "Configuration.h"

@interface Configuration ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *config;

@end

@implementation Configuration

+(instancetype)sharedConfig
{
    static Configuration *instance = nil;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [[Configuration alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *configPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"plist"];
        self.config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:configPath];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)GoogleAnalyticsID
{
    return self.config[@"GAnalytics"];
}

@end
```

**appdelegate.m**

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId: [[Configuration sharedConfig] GoogleAnalyticsID]];
```

Comment: what is key in Plist? can you nslog in  **GoogleAnalyticsID** function before return the value.

Comment: Is that really what the plist file looks like? It needs to be an XML file with a very specific format.